# Composer giving error after updating to version 2

Tags: php, composer-php

I updated my composer to version 2. Here is my `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "periperi",
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "2.10.*",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.28",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

The name was peri-peri, but it was giving error

```
[Composer\Json\JsonValidationException]                                                                     
  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:                                                  
   - name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

I changed the name to periperi, but it still gives same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to use the same `composer.json` with composer 1.10.19 you would get:

> Deprecation warning: Your package name periperi is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^a-z0-9*/a-z0-9*$". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.

Basically, the project name needs to be: 'vendor/name'. Choose a vendor name for your "organization", and you can use the same package name. If your project is not a library, do not worry much about the "vendor" name. It can be simply your name and it wont be published anywhere. E.g `muhammad-umar/periperi` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The vendor name is expected to have format:

```
vendor-name/package-name
```

Eg.:

```
muhammad-umar/periperi
```